# How to source a catkin_package?

Tags: ros, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a package using catkin_create_pkg dependencies only roscpp
created a node using c++ code and then edited CMakelist.txt then I used catkin_make to build it.
the next step i need to do it is to run the following to ......

source devel/setup.bash

after this I tried to run the node by

rosrun

it showing error that can not find package

What i understand is that my package is not sourced properly to ROS?
Please tell the solution.
If i am wrong then please correct me and tell the solution.

PS: following the Prof. Jason O'Kane tutorial on ROS linked on ros.org

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66273/how-to-source-a-catkin_package-?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can source as below:

source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

Check if catkin_make was successful and your package is built and linked with libraries successfully. Then try using rosrun command again.

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-06-30**:
Thank you Devasena,Finally I got to perform. I am at initial learning stage, may need your help again soon. Thank you for your reply.